# SQL selecting name, number, and a count in a single query

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have 2 tables, Courses and Register.
Courses holds a name and a number of a course, Register holds a course number and a student number.
I need to select the course number, course name, and the number of students enrolled in each course.
I just started SQL and I have no idea how to do this.  I keep getting errors about nonaggregated columns and such.
How would I go about selecting these things in a single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT C.ID, C.NAME, COUNT(R.STUDENT_ID) FROM COURSE C INNER JOIN REGISTER R ON C.ID = R.COURSE_ID GROUP BY C.ID`

I believe it would like this.